# MSSQL Access From Zend2 via Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux, zend-framework2

I'm upgrading an application that presently runs on ZendFramework1(ZF1) to ZendFramework2(ZF2). I'm having trouble getting DB results to return from the ZF2 connection.

In ZF1 this test works perfectly:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mssql', array(
    'host'     => 'ServerNameFromFreeTdsConfig',
    'charset'   => 'UTF-8',
    'username' => 'myUsername',
    'password' => 'myPassword',
    'dbname'   => 'database_name',
    'pdoType'  => 'dblib'
));

$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from Products");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
```

However, I've been trying this in ZF2 but I'm not really getting anywhere. In my config\autoload\global.php I have:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'host'  => 'ServerNameFromFreeTdsConfig',
        'charset'   => 'UTF-8',
        'dbname'  => 'database_name',
        'username'  => 'myUsername',
        'password'  => 'myPassword',
        'driver'    => 'pdo',
        'pdodriver' => 'dblib',
    ),
);
```

And in the Module.php file:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $config = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Configuration');
    $dbAdapter = new Adapter($config['db'], new SqlServer());

    GlobalAdapterFeature::setStaticAdapter($dbAdapter);
}
```

Then in the Model\Products.php

```
class Products extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table;
    protected $featureSet;

    public function __construct($table = 'Products') {
        $this->table = $table;
        $this->featureSet = new FeatureSet();
        $this->featureSet->addFeature(new GlobalAdapterFeature());
        $this->initialize();
    }

    //Test the connection.
    public function getProducts() {   
        $result = $this->getAdapter()->query("select * from Products", Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
die(var_dump($result));
    }
}
```

It looks like it is connecting because the "var_dump" above returns a ["fieldCount":protected]=> int(7) which is correct (there are 7 columns in that table). However, it is not returning any results.
What might I need to do to get this to work in ZF2? Do I need to somehow extend Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter using code from the ZF1 Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql.php file? Or is there some simple solution I'm missing?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own Adapter adopted from the Zend Framework 1 adapter I had working there. If someone comes across this post looking for a solution to the same problem and would like a copy of the code I transposed, let me know. There is quite a lot of code or I'd post it here.

Comment: I would be interested in the adapter that you wrote.  weatheredwatcher (at) gmail dot com

Comment: @David Just sent. Let me know if you run into problems and I'll try to help out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to mention the user name and password

```
resources.db.adapter = "sqlsrv"
resources.db.host = "localhost\SQLEXPRESS"
resources.db.dbname = "DatabaseName"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true 
resources.db.driver_options.ReturnDatesAsStrings = true
```

Comment: I'm not so sure the variables you listed above will work with Zend Framework 2, will they? The docs [link]http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.adapter.html specifically mention the key names Zend 2 will accept in the configuration array sent to the adapter. Is there another way to connect?